# Component DatePicker / Calendar

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I read on roadmap http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/roadmap/ about components like **DatePicker, TimePicker, DateTimePicker, Calendar**.
I don't find pickers component on documentation.
Are they released?
Any news here?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following discussion: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/200

Comment: Also an answer of the Kendo UI PM can be found here:
https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/194